# Return Status while cap.isOpened() at command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I read an mp4 video with Python 3.6.5 and OpenCV 3.4.1 and do some (resource-heavy) calculations with every single frame.

I have the total number for frames (`length`) and the current one (`count`) of course, so I'd like to give a progress update in my command line, but unfortunately it shows everything only after the whole process is finished.

```
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        # Calculation stuff
        ...

        # Print the current status
        print("Frame %s/%s" % (count, length))

        count = count + 1
```

Unfortunately it only prints ALL after the video file is completely processed.
How can I print a "live" status of the current frame?

I use MINGW64 (Windows) as my Console

Comment: Are there by any change `continue`s in your code (before the `print` part)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first look, this is due to the fact that you probably have *control flow* directives in your code (like `break`, `continue`, etc.), that prevent the interpreter from reaching the line.

Therefore you should make sure that either you print before these directives, your we can simply print at the top, like:

```
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print("Frame %s/%s" % (count, length))
    count += 1

    if ret:
        # Calculation stuff
        # ...
        pass
```

That being said, we can turn this capture procedure into a *generator* that prints the values, with a nice progress bar, like:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from cv2 import CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT

def frame_iter(capture, description):
    def _itertor():
        while capture.grab():
            yield capture.retrieve()[1]
    return tqdm(
        _iterator(),
        desc=description,
        total=int(capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)),
    )
```

Then we can use it like:

```
for frame in frame_iter(capture, 'some description'):
    # process the frame
    pass
```

It will display a progress bar like demonstrated in the [GitHub repository of `tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

Comment: No control flows, it ended up to be an issue with MINGW under Windows but I ended up using your code anyway, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**OpenCV writer in tqdm**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input.MP4")
outcap = cv2.VideoWriter("output.MP4",     cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('H','2','6','4'), 30, (int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

print(int(inpcap.get(3)),int(inpcap.get(4)))
print("total frames :",crame_count)

i = 1
pbar = tqdm(total = frame_count)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    pbar.update(i)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
       print('completed...!')
    out.write(frame)

cap.release()
cap.release()
```